# react - getting unauthorized from rest api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, axios, laravel-sanctum

I am working on a project where I have used Laravel 9 for the backend and React for the frontend. Whenever i try to make a request it return `unauthorized` from the backed. But when i try this on the postman it return success response.

I am sure the problem is in my react js code.

```
 const Submited = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/customer/store", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer" + cookies.jwt,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
       
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
   
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an space character after Bearer

Comment: I put some space after bearer. but the problem is with the post request. Get request successfully works.

Comment: Set headers at 3rd parameter, like this: `axios.post(url, {}, {headers:...});`